# What's the formula used in solving this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{a^{\sqrt{x}}} {\sqrt{x}}dx$$

I understand that the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ can be used, but there was another method which went by this:

$$\int\frac{a^{\sqrt{x}}} {\sqrt{x}}dx = 2\int\frac{a^{\sqrt{x}}} {2\sqrt{x}}dx = \frac{2a^{\sqrt{x}}} {lna}+C$$

What is the formula used here?

Comment: $$2\int \frac{a^{\sqrt{x}}}{2\sqrt{x}}\, dx=2\int a^{\sqrt{x}}\, d(\sqrt{x})=$$

$$=\frac{2}{\ln(a)}\int e^{\ln(a)\sqrt{x}}\, d(\ln(a)\sqrt{x})=$$

$$=\frac{2}{\ln(a)}e^{\ln(a)\sqrt{x}}+C=\frac{2}{\ln(a)}a^{\sqrt{x}}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is $\frac{d}{dx}a^{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: $\frac{a^{\sqrt{x}}} {2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @user373534 Yes. So...?

Comment: I'm only aware of $\int\frac{f'(x)} {f(x)}dx = ln|f(x)| + C$. EDIT: oh wait.

Comment: why would there be a $lna$ then?

Comment: @user373534 Well, your derivative is actually wrong and you should get a $\log a$ also, because $a^{\sqrt{x}}=e^{\sqrt{x}\log a}$.

Comment: oh jeez. Thank you very much.